# LoadImage() returns NULL when trying to load bitmap image from disk

Tags: c++, winapi

I have this directory structure:

```
---- test.cpp
---- test.exe (created after compiling test.cpp)
---- sample.bmp
```

I have this code, which (for the time being) reads the image `sample.bmp` and stores it in a `HBITMAP` handle:

```c
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HWND sampleImg = CreateWindowEx(0, "Static", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        /* --------------HERE----------------- */
        HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "D:\\Rest\\New Folder\\sample.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

        if (hBitmap == NULL)
        {
            /* This block is reached, hBitmap is NULL */
            MessageBox(NULL, "LoadImage failed", "Error", MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }

        SendMessage(sampleImg, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
    }
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "Test";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow("Test", "Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

I tried to call `GetLastError()` and check the error code. The error code is 0 (`ERROR_SUCCESS`), implying there are no errors.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Directory structure of `D:/Rest/New Folder`:

[image]

I wanted to fetch a bitmap image, but the necessary routine returns NULL.

Comment: Have you checked `GetLastError()` after `LoadBitmap`? What does it return? Use `FormatMessage` to get a human-readable error description or look up the system error code manually.

Comment: `LoadImage()` should not be failing with an error code of 0. Are you calling `GetLastError()` *immediately* after `LoadImage()` fails, with no other calls in between? Please update your question to show your call to `GetLastError()` and how you are displaying the error code.

Comment: If bitmap file is invalid, `LoadImage` fails, `GetLastError` is zero.

Comment: I called GetLastError() inside the if block before the call to the MessageBox function.  I wrote a little code to write the error code to a file (`fprintf(file, "%d", GetLastError())`). Kindly let me know if there is a problem in this method to check error code. The file had 0 written in it. As for the bitmap file, I downloaded it from internet and it loads perfectly in image viewer.

Comment: Image viewer and other apps can be more forgiving. For example they will try to pick the right image format even if the extension is wrong. Use Windows "Paint" program to create a bitmap file and "Save as" bitmap file.

Comment: By the way, you are supposed to use `DWORD err = GetLastError(); fprintf(file, "%d", err);` otherwise `fprintf` could cause a separate error. Although in this case it probably makes no difference, and `GetLastError` stays at zero.